# Which is best: botany lab, botanical lab or flora lab?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

English is not my native language. Please, tell me how do I refer to a laboratory that studies flora: botany lab, botanical lab or flora lab?

Comment: [Please learn to look these things up for yourself](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=botany+lab%2Cbotanical+lab%2Cflora+lab&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbotany%20lab%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @tchrist Thanks, I didn't know that tool. I looked in google for the three options and each had similar results. This link is much more reliable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Botany Lab - use the noun with lab as it's a lab that studies botany.

Botanical is an adjective, so you use it for things like the Botanical Gardens.

The link tchrist commented above is an extremely useful place to compare words or phrases to see which is the most common.